# Cancellation statistics in R

Tags: r, statistics, plyr

Sorry for the noob question: I'm trying to count daily statistics in R. There are multiple appointments per date, and 3 different statuses: "Confirmed", "Cancelled", and "Late Cancellation".

I've tried `table(data)` which seems to do the correct counts, but it takes all the dates out of order. Is there a way to fix that, or how can I do the counts without losing the order of the dates?

```
> data[25:35,]

        Date             Status
25  9/8/2012          Confirmed
26  9/8/2012          Confirmed
27  9/8/2012          Cancelled
28  9/8/2012          Confirmed
29  9/9/2012          Confirmed
30  9/9/2012          Confirmed
31  9/9/2012          Cancelled
32  9/9/2012          Confirmed
33  9/9/2012  Late Cancellation
34  9/9/2012          Confirmed
35 9/10/2012          Confirmed
```

This is a simplified version of ~1000 appointments over 3 months (there are also room numbers, customer types, etc. in the full set) so I'm hoping to understand how to count & sort data in R with this simple example.

If I create a new vector of unique dates using `unique(data$Date)` can I use that as bins to sort the status counts into?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `count` from the `plyr` package to do this. Let's load your data:

```
dat = read.table(text = "        Date             Status
 9/8/2012          Confirmed
 9/8/2012          Confirmed
 9/8/2012          Cancelled
 9/8/2012          Confirmed
 9/9/2012          Confirmed
 9/9/2012          Confirmed
 9/9/2012          Cancelled
 9/9/2012          Confirmed
 9/9/2012  LateCancellation
 9/9/2012          Confirmed
 9/10/2012          Confirmed", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

First we need to transform `Date` to a proper time aware datatype instead of a character string:

```
dat[["Date"]] = strptime(dat[["Date"]], format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and perform the count:

```
require(plyr)
cdat = count(dat, c("Date", "Status"))
> cdat
        Date           Status freq
1 2012-09-08        Cancelled    1
2 2012-09-08        Confirmed    3
3 2012-09-09        Cancelled    1
4 2012-09-09        Confirmed    4
5 2012-09-09 LateCancellation    1
6 2012-09-10        Confirmed    1
```

Notice that the dates are now in the correct order, this is because of the transformation using `strptime`. If you want output which looks like what `table` does, you need to perform some tweaking with `dcast` from the `reshape2` package:

```
> dcast(cdat, Date ~ Status, value.var = "freq")
        Date Cancelled Confirmed LateCancellation
1 2012-09-08         1         3               NA
2 2012-09-09         1         4                1
3 2012-09-10        NA         1               NA
```